# Show next key in dictionary based on user action - python

Tags: python, flask

I'm attempting to write a function for a python quiz that will show the next key (entitled "question") in a dictionary based on a user action. I already have the functionality to check that the answer is correct but I'm struggling for it to then show the next key (question). I am also giving the user 3 attempts to solve the question so the next question cannot show unless either a) the question is answered or b) they run out of guesses.

I have played around with for loops and while loops but all I seem to be able to do is repeat the same thing over and over again. Should I be using the range parameter or something else??

```
riddles=[]
with open("data/riddles.json") as riddles_file:
    riddles = json.load(riddles_file)

def right_answer(answer, riddle):
    return answer == riddle["answer"]

def next_question(riddles):    
    for riddle in riddles:
        #run the first question. If question correct, run the next question. 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'some_secret' 

@app.route('/<user>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def quiz(user):

    riddle = riddles[0]
    #hard coded to show first question 

    max_guesses = 3

    counter = 0

    if request.method == "POST":
        answer = request.form.get("answer")

        while counter < max_guesses:
            if right_answer(answer, riddle):
                game_status[user] += 1
                next_question(riddles)
                return render_template("user.html", user=user, score=game_status[user], question=riddle["question"], message = "Correct. Well done!")

            else:
                counter += 1
                guesses_left = max_guesses - counter
                print("answer")
                return render_template("user.html", user=user, score=game_status[user], question=riddle["question"], message = "This is wrong. Try again. Your remaining guesses are:", guesses = guesses_left, answer = answer)

    return render_template("user.html", user=user, score=game_status[user], question=riddle["question"] )
```

Answer (score 0):

the way i'd do it: quiz would have a riddle_number argument with its default set to 0

```
def quiz(user, riddle_number=0):

    riddle = riddles[riddle_number]
```

your while has a bad test: it is only meant for failures. instead create a flag

```
    next_riddle = False
    while not next_riddle:
        if right_answer(answer, riddle):
            next_riddle = True
            [...]

        else:
            guesses_left = max_guesses - counter
            if guesses_left == 0:
                next_riddle = True
            [...]
```

then i'call quiz with `riddle_number+1`